# Ripple Phone Gap Emulator - methods such as exec() and stringify()

Tags: cordova, ripple

The Ripple plugin for Chrome emulates most of the PhoneGap APIs, but I'm using a third-party piece of software that uses APIs such as PhoneGap.exec() and PhoneGap.stringify() and so far as I can see I don't get those in the Ripple environment.

My work-around is to hack those methods into PhoneGap at a late stage in the initialisation. This does seem to work but feels like a kluge.

Questions:

1). Is there a trick to making such APIs available in Ripple?

2). Any suggestions for a clean work-around?

Answer (score 1):

I think the ripple is still in beta mode if you are talking about the ripple from rim. I know previously with rim html5 implementations that there was a config file where you could specify services you would use from the phone.... Maybe within that same config file you can specify certain methods the key would be to find the ripple implementation of that config file and check if that option actualy exists...

Comment: Thanks, so far as I can tell the version I'm using simply doesn't have the code for the missing methods.

Answer (score 0):

I could be very wrong but my understanding is that the `exec` function is for executing native code so it would be exceedingly difficult for Ripple to implement it if it were possible at all. And `stringify` seems to have been removed from recent versions of Cordova (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-commits/201201.mbox/%3C20120103185712.5EDCE315778@tyr.zones.apache.org%3E).

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code I found that when PhoneGap wants to call a plugin ripple catch the last call (the exec method) and overrides the native implementation with its one.

this is ripple code:

```
var _prompt = ripple('ui/plugins/exec-dialog'),
emulator = {
    "App": ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge/app'),
    "Accelerometer": ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge/accelerometer'),
    "Battery" : ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge/battery'),
    "Compass": ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge/compass'),
    "Camera": ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge/camera'),
    ...   
};
module.exports = {
    add: function (service, module) {
        emulator[service] = module;
    },
    exec: function (success, fail, service, action, args) {
        try {
            emulator[service][action](success, fail, args);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("missing exec:" + service + "." + action);
            console.log(args);
            console.log(e);
            console.log(e.stack);

        _prompt.show(service, action, success, fail);
        }
    }
};
```

so I make this call before using my plugin:

```
ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge').add("ToggleBluetooth", {
                                                                        start: function(){
                                                                            console.log("this is a native method call emulation");
                                                                            return true;
                                                                        },
                                                                        stop: function(){
                                                                            console.log("this is a native method call emulation");
                                                                            return true;
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                );
```

In this way Ripple knows what to do instead of throwing exception.

I'm using ripple 0.9.23